# Converting JSON into newline delimited JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

My goal is to convert JSON file into a format that can uploaded from Cloud Storage into BigQuery ([as described here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json)) with Python.

I have tried using [newlineJSON](https://github.com/geowurster/NewlineJSON) package for the conversion but receives the following error.

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value or ']': line 2 column 1 (char 5)
```

Does anyone have the solution to this?

Here is the sample JSON code:

```
[{
    "key01": "value01",
    "key02": "value02",
    ...
    "keyN": "valueN"
},
{
    "key01": "value01",
    "key02": "value02",
    ...
    "keyN": "valueN"
},
{
    "key01": "value01",
    "key02": "value02",
    ...
    "keyN": "valueN"
}
]
```

And here's the existing python script:

```
with nlj.open(url_samplejson, json_lib = "simplejson") as src_:
    with nlj.open(url_convertedjson, "w") as dst_:
        for line_ in src_:
            dst_.write(line_)
```

Comment: Here's the bigquery documentation that has an example to load json into a table use the bigquery client python api:  https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.load_table_from_json

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The answer with `jq` is really useful, but if you still want to do it with Python (as it seems from the question), you can do it with built-in `json` module.

```
import json
from io import StringIO
in_json = StringIO("""[{
    "key01": "value01",
    "key02": "value02",

    "keyN": "valueN"
},
{
    "key01": "value01",
    "key02": "value02",

    "keyN": "valueN"
},
{
    "key01": "value01",
    "key02": "value02",

    "keyN": "valueN"
}
]""")

result = [json.dumps(record) for record in json.load(in_json)]  # the only significant line to convert the JSON to the desired format

print('\n'.join(result))

{"key01": "value01", "key02": "value02", "keyN": "valueN"}
{"key01": "value01", "key02": "value02", "keyN": "valueN"}
{"key01": "value01", "key02": "value02", "keyN": "valueN"}
```

* I'm using `StringIO` and `print` here just to make a sample easier to test locally.

As an alternative, you can use [Python jq binding](https://pypi.org/project/jq/) to combine it with [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51301075/7732200).

Comment: Also works for python objects (as opposed to strings of JSON) like this: result = [json.dumps(item) for item in items]

Comment: I think this is the best answer. To combine with the file writing operation, I used this answer to produce the following snippet:
    `data = df.to_dict('records')`
    `output = open('test.json', 'w')`
    `output.write('\n'.join([json.dumps(record) for record in data]))`
    `output.close()`

Answer (score 26):

If you are willing to get out of Python, use `jq`:

```
$ cat a.json 
[{
    "key01": "value01",
    "key02": "value02",
    "keyN": "valueN"
},
{
    "key01": "value01",
    "key02": "value02",
    "keyN": "valueN"
},
{
    "key01": "value01",
    "key02": "value02",
    "keyN": "valueN"
}
]


$ cat a.json | jq -c '.[]'
{"key01":"value01","key02":"value02","keyN":"valueN"}
{"key01":"value01","key02":"value02","keyN":"valueN"}
{"key01":"value01","key02":"value02","keyN":"valueN"}
```

The iterator I used is `'.[]'` to go through the array, and `-c` puts each JSON object on a single line.

Resources:

- https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/
- https://github.com/stedolan/jq

Comment: Very efficient way of converting. Will implement this when using jq.

Comment: Hi, do you also have the command to perform the opposite action? From new-line delimited to well-formed json array

Comment: Perfect. But at first, I mistakenly grabbed `jq` via npm which didn't work out very well.

Comment: Within node.js, I was able to use the `node-jq` library to do the same. ```jq.run('.[]', 'data.json', {output: 'compact'})
    .then((output) => {
        dataStream.push(output)
        dataStream.push(null)

        dataStream.pipe(gcFile.createWriteStream({
            resumable: false,
            validation: false,
            metadata: { 'Cache-Control': 'public, max-age=31536000' }
        }))
    
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })```

Comment: How do you install jq? according to the jq page linked (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/), I should "Use Chocolatey NuGet to install jq 1.5 with chocolatey install jq" - I've never heard of chocolatey before and don't get why i need to install more stuff to get to jq?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/jq/ `pip install jq`

Answer (score 13):

**This takes a JSON file and converts into ND-JSON file.**

```
import json

with open("results-20190312-113458.json", "r") as read_file:
    data = json.load(read_file)
result = [json.dumps(record) for record in data]
with open('nd-proceesed.json', 'w') as obj:
    for i in result:
        obj.write(i+'\n')
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This method can easily be adapted to write streaming data.

Comment: This wont iterate inside nested objects.

Answer (score 0):

```py
with open('out.json', 'w') as f:
  for obj in objs:
    json.dump(obj, f)
    f.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

if the files are large you may want to use a faster module such as `msgspec` or `orjson` as they use c (or c++ I don't fully know but there faster)

example:

- read

```py
with open('test.json', 'rb') as f:
    j = msgspec.json.decode(f.read())
    
j = b'\n'.join(map(msgspec.json.encode, j))
```

- write

```
with open('test.json', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(j)
```