# JSON formatting Error when loading into Google Big Query

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I am trying to load the following data in Big Query from PUBSUB using the built in dataflow template:

```
{
    "current_speed": "19.09",
    "_east": "-87.654561",
    "_last_updt": "2018-07-17 15:50:54.0",
    "_region_id": "1",
    "_north": "42.026444",
    "_south": "41.997946",
    "region": "Rogers Park - West Ridge",
    "_west": "-87.709645",
    "_description": "North of Devon. Kedzie to Lake Shore"
}
```

But I keeping getting this error:

> "Error while reading data, error message: Failed to parse JSON:
>   Unexpected end of string; Unexpected end of string; Expected key"

I actually need to load the larger dataset which looks like this:

```
 [{
    "current_speed": "19.09",
    "_east": "-87.654561",
    "_last_updt": "2018-07-17 15:50:54.0",
    "_region_id": "1",
    "_north": "42.026444",
    "_south": "41.997946",
    "region": "Rogers Park - West Ridge",
    "_west": "-87.709645",
    "_description": "North of Devon. Kedzie to Lake Shore"
}, {
    "current_speed": "25.23",
    "_east": "-87.747456",
    "_last_updt": "2018-07-17 15:50:54.0",
    "_region_id": "2",
    "_north": "42.0190998",
    "_south": "41.960669",
    "region": "Far North West",
    "_west": "-87.84621",
    "_description": "North of Montrose. East River to Cicero"
}
```

]

But there I get this error:

> Error while reading data, error message: Failed to parse JSON: No
>   object found when new array is started.; BeginArray returned false;
>   Parser terminated before end of string

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It is not clear who/what is sending that error message - and how you are executing it. Can you add more implementation details?

Comment: Hi @FelipeHoffa Thanks for your reply. I am trying to upload my JSON using BQ UI to test it before I implement my pipeline. I actually made some progress. What I found out was BQ likes this "{ "current_speed" : "19.77", "_east" : "-87.654561", "_last_updt" : "2018-07-17 15:31:30.0", "_region_id" : "1", "_north" : "42.026444", "_south" : "41.997946", "region" : "Rogers Park - West Ridge", "_west" : "-87.709645", "_description" : "North of Devon. Kedzie to Lake Shore" }" i.e. with no newline between elements. But still donno what to do with array.

Comment: To reclarify: I am now able to insert single json objects, but not an array. From my initial object I had to remove all newlines and compress the whole thing in one line. I think thats weird, but its working atleast.

Comment: Please post a new question for the new problem - and please, if you are importing directly into BigQuery without using Pub/Sub or Dataflow - indicate so.

Comment: Aah! This is what "newline delimited" means! Geez. What an ambiguous name. "Single line object formatted JSON" would be univocal...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, BigQuery only accepts new-line delimited JSON, which means one complete JSON object per line. Before you merge the object to one line, BigQuery reads "{", which is start of an object, and expects to read a key, but the line ended, so you see the error message "expected key".

For multiple JSON objects, just put them one in each line. Don't enclose them inside an array. BigQuery expects each line to start with an object, "{". If you put "[" as the first character, you will see the second error message which means BigQuery reads an array but not inside an object.

Comment: Super interesting. Thanks Hua. I have a huge object which I receive as an array. Now I need to convert this into non-array somehow. BTW, shouldn't BQ be able to handle arrays as well? I would expect that to be quite a common scenario, no?

Comment: Arrays inside an object is supported. It converts to a REPEATED field in BigQuery. But array out of an object is not accepted. Strictly speaking you cannot receive a JSON object as an array. A JSON object always starts with "{", http://www.json.org/. A JSON object can have an array property: {"string_array": ["apple", "banana"]}.

Comment: For reference: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json#limitations

Answer (score 31):

To convert JSON to new line delimited JSON (which is the format that BigQuery ingests) you can use `jq`:

```
$ cat a.json 
[{
    "key01": "value01",
    "key02": "value02",
    "keyN": "valueN"
},
{
    "key01": "value01",
    "key02": "value02",
    "keyN": "valueN"
},
{
    "key01": "value01",
    "key02": "value02",
    "keyN": "valueN"
}
]


$ cat a.json | jq -c '.[]'
{"key01":"value01","key02":"value02","keyN":"valueN"}
{"key01":"value01","key02":"value02","keyN":"valueN"}
{"key01":"value01","key02":"value02","keyN":"valueN"}
```

(see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51301075/132438)

Comment: what would be done if one wanted to convert a large sized file? Say the file was ~7GB, it seems as this command wouldn't work. Any advice?

Comment: on mac os, I didn't have jq installed (command not found), so I ran brew install jq