# Converting Google Cloud Video intelligence json to newline delimited json to upload to Big Query

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, jq, video-intelligence-api

I have created a function which outputs the json below from using the Google Video Intelligence API. I am trying to get the json into newline delimited format so that I can upload the json file to Big Query.

I have tried the following JQ code however it does not convert it into a format accepted by BiG Query.

Any help greatly appreciated.

$ cat a.json | jq -c '.[]'

Full json output from video intelligence

```
{
  "annotation_results": [ {
    "input_uri": "/mastersproject-252719.appspot.com/AEnB2UoTKtyPJd1X88yUBKC60dn3kp6qrnnE91Q5PylS9RqotQWrt2TzFPE7kG1UHtxoBYyWX5mo7zoXU1jzwnNe_WRD-t0QeFSoHU4g-WJZTfeQV4cpFNY.4-FicKZIT3vtFBd2",
    "segment": {
      "start_time_offset": {

      },
      "end_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 126,
        "nanos": 160000000
      }
    },
    "shot_annotations": [ {
      "start_time_offset": {

      },
      "end_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 3,
        "nanos": 960000000
      }
    }, {
      "start_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 4
      },
      "end_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 5,
        "nanos": 840000000
      }
    }, {
      "start_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 5,
        "nanos": 880000000
      },
      "end_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 11,
        "nanos": 40000000
      }
    }, {
      "start_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 11,
        "nanos": 80000000
      },
      "end_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 14,
        "nanos": 640000000
      }
    }, {
      "start_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 14,
        "nanos": 680000000
      },
      "end_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 15,
        "nanos": 400000000
      }
    }, {
      "start_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 15,
        "nanos": 440000000
      },
      "end_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 19,
        "nanos": 840000000
      }
    }, {
      "start_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 19,
        "nanos": 880000000
      },
      "end_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 21,
        "nanos": 880000000
      }
    }, {
      "start_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 21,
        "nanos": 920000000
      },
      "end_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 25,
        "nanos": 120000000
      }
    }, {
      "start_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 25,
        "nanos": 160000000
      },
      "end_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 30,
        "nanos": 880000000
      }
    }, {
      "start_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 30,
        "nanos": 920000000
      },
      "end_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 32,
        "nanos": 960000000
      }
    }, {
      "start_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 33
      },
      "end_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 38,
        "nanos": 80000000
      }
    }, {
      "start_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 38,
        "nanos": 120000000
      },
      "end_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 44,
        "nanos": 80000000
      }
    }, {
      "start_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 44,
        "nanos": 120000000
      },
      "end_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 47,
        "nanos": 680000000
      }
    }, {
      "start_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 47,
        "nanos": 720000000
      },
      "end_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 51,
        "nanos": 120000000
      }
    }, {
      "start_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 51,
        "nanos": 160000000
      },
      "end_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 56,
        "nanos": 640000000
      }
    }, {
      "start_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 56,
        "nanos": 680000000
      },
      "end_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 59,
        "nanos": 40000000
      }
    }, {
      "start_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 59,
        "nanos": 80000000
      },
      "end_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 62,
        "nanos": 880000000
      }
    }, {
      "start_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 62,
        "nanos": 920000000
      },
      "end_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 70,
        "nanos": 640000000
      }
    }, {
      "start_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 70,
        "nanos": 680000000
      },
      "end_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 74,
        "nanos": 240000000
      }
    }, {
      "start_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 74,
        "nanos": 280000000
      },
      "end_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 76,
        "nanos": 40000000
      }
    }, {
      "start_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 76,
        "nanos": 80000000
      },
      "end_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 82,
        "nanos": 240000000
      }
    }, {
      "start_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 82,
        "nanos": 280000000
      },
      "end_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 86
      }
    }, {
      "start_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 86,
        "nanos": 40000000
      },
      "end_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 89,
        "nanos": 720000000
      }
    }, {
      "start_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 89,
        "nanos": 760000000
      },
      "end_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 99,
        "nanos": 680000000
      }
    }, {
      "start_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 99,
        "nanos": 720000000
      },
      "end_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 104,
        "nanos": 360000000
      }
    }, {
      "start_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 104,
        "nanos": 400000000
      },
      "end_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 107,
        "nanos": 440000000
      }
    }, {
      "start_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 107,
        "nanos": 480000000
      },
      "end_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 108,
        "nanos": 640000000
      }
    }, {
      "start_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 108,
        "nanos": 680000000
      },
      "end_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 112,
        "nanos": 160000000
      }
    }, {
      "start_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 112,
        "nanos": 200000000
      },
      "end_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 114,
        "nanos": 640000000
      }
    }, {
      "start_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 114,
        "nanos": 680000000
      },
      "end_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 117,
        "nanos": 520000000
      }
    }, {
      "start_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 117,
        "nanos": 560000000
      },
      "end_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 118,
        "nanos": 760000000
      }
    }, {
      "start_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 118,
        "nanos": 800000000
      },
      "end_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 121,
        "nanos": 80000000
      }
    }, {
      "start_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 121,
        "nanos": 120000000
      },
      "end_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 122,
        "nanos": 320000000
      }
    }, {
      "start_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 122,
        "nanos": 360000000
      },
      "end_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 124,
        "nanos": 200000000
      }
    }, {
      "start_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 124,
        "nanos": 240000000
      },
      "end_time_offset": {
        "seconds": 126,
        "nanos": 160000000
      }
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you tried the suggested JQ command in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51300674/converting-json-into-newline-delimited-json-in-python) stack overflow post. You need to use a different JQ command suited to your case.

I personally tried:

```
cat <filename>.json | jq -c '.'
```

and it works. Meaning, the end result is a valid newline delimited json.

However, it may need more tweaks depending on your end table schema.

Include your end table schema on the description if it does not work so we can understand better what is the goal.