# Convert a large file JSON into newline delimited JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I tried to convert a JSON file to ndJSON so that I can upload it to GCS and write it as BQ table. I've tried everything in here [Converting JSON into newline delimited JSON in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51300674/converting-json-into-newline-delimited-json-in-python) but doesn't work in my case, because I have a 7GBs JSON file.

I tried using this python code

```py
import json

with open("input.json", "r") as read_file:
    data = json.load(read_file)
result = [json.dumps(record) for record in data]
with open('nd-output.json', 'w') as obj:
    for i in result:
        obj.write(i+'\n')
```

But it raised

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_py_file.py", line 4, in <module>
    data = json.load(read_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
MemoryError
```

Then I tried `jq` method but still no luck

```bash
cat input.json | jq -c '.[]'
```

It raised

```
1477 broken pipe  cat input.json |
1478 killed       jq -c '.[]'
```

Is there anything that I can do to achieve my goal?

Comment: Something like [this](https://pypi.org/project/json-stream/) seems like it'd be useful.

Comment: MemoryError indicates that Python runs out of memory. If it enforces arbitrary limits, that would be a possible parameter you could tweak.

Comment: Make sure you are using 64-bit Python and add more memory if needed. *Why* do you have 7GB JSON file in the first place??

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it is clear that the error you got is related to the availability of system memory.Instead of loading the entire json file into memory, you can load a small portion of data at once and then you can load the next portion and so on. Please refer to the code below. In this code, the package [`ijson`](https://pypi.org/project/ijson/) is used to convert json to ndjson portion by portion. Also, please note that Google does not officially support `ijson`.

```
import ijson
 
with open('nd-output.json', 'w') as writefile:
   with open('input.json', 'r') as data:
       for obj in ijson.items(data, 'item'):
           writefile.write(str(obj)+'\n')
```