# Reading multilines JSON with Apache Beam in Python

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm having trouble reading JSON files from Google Cloud Storage correctly.
The format of the input looks like this in his basic structure:

```
[
 {
   "id": "CANT14",
   "entity": "Comunità del Collio",
  },
]
```

If I save the file on my computer and minify it so that it is structured in one line the pipeline works:

```
[{"id": "CANT14","entity": "Comunità del Collio"}]
```

The problem is that I need to read the file directly from Google Cloud Storage without any further steps.

The pipeline looks like it:

```
with beam.Pipeline() as p:
    # Read JSON file from Google Storage bucket
    content = (p | "Read file" >> beam.io.ReadFromText(bucket))

     # Parse JSON
    json = content | 'Parse JSON' >> beam.Map(json.loads)

    # Print result
    json | 'Print content' >> beam.Map(print)
```

Here the error:

```
RuntimeError: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

I have already checked the JSON, also through various online tools and it is valid. The only problem is that it's just a multiline JSON.

This is my first time using Apache Beam and I'm probably missing something.
Is there any way to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: I proposed you an answer, I hope it will help to solve your issue. Can you check it please ?

Comment: Hello, thank you very much! Is there a way to transform the JSON that comes from Google Cloud Storage into a ndJSON before passing it to the pipeline?

Comment: I edited my answer to share a link with `jq`. This tool allows to transform standard `Json` file to new delimited json file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read `Json` file with `Apache Beam` and native `ReadFromText` input connector, the format of `Json` file should be `NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON`, example :

```json
{"id":"CANT14","entity":"Comunità del Collio"}
{"id":"CANT15","entity2":"Comunità del Collio"}
```

With this format each `Json` object is put on one line, without coma to separate them.

You can transform your standard `Json` to `NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON` with `jq` using a separate process before to launch the `Dataflow` job.
You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51300674/converting-json-into-newline-delimited-json-in-python) to have more info and help.